# Reversal Traversing in circular buffer in C

Tags: c, linux

I have the following array which I intend to use it as circular buffer.

```
int array1[20];
```

The array is written by one thread and read by another thread. While reading I need to read the last 3 values written in that array.

Writing works fine. I use

```
writeIndex = (writeIndex + 1) %20;
```

to write. This rolls over array Index 0 to 19 nicely.

For reading I'm using

```
readIndex = (readIndex -1)%20;
```

but it doesn't work When I try to go from index 0 to 19.

Comment: Put some more code here.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to read `writeIndex - 2`, `writeIndex - 1`, and `writeIndex`? So `readIndex = (writeIndex - 2) % 20` will give the start of the last 3 writes.

Comment: Do you really need to go in reverse, and not forward but from a different position?

Comment: Try `readIndex = (readIndex + 19)%20;`. You don't want to deal with negative numbers in this case.

Comment: Note that if you maintain `readIndex` and `writeIndex`, it is hard to store 20 items.  When `readIndex == writeIndex`, does that mean the queue is full or the queue is empty?  (See Knuth §2.2.2 exercise 1.)  The simplest solution is instead to maintain `readIndex` and `count`, where `count` is the number of items currently in the queue, and compute `writeIndex` from those whenever you need it.

Comment: Thanks, Yuxiu Li. It did the trick.

Comment: @YuxiuLi Why don't you make an answer out of it, so we could vote on it?

Comment: @YuxiuLi Great, you got my vote :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code

```
readIndex = (readIndex - 1) % 20;
```

is not working because when `readIndex` begins with 0, `(readIndex - 1) % 20` will evaulate to -1 and then your array access will be out of bound.

You don't want to deal with negative numbers in this case. To avoid it from happening you can simply add 20 to the value:

```
readIndex = (readIndex - 1 + 20) % 20;
```

or simply

```
readIndex = (readIndex + 19) % 20;
```

So when `readIndex` starts with 0, you can wrap around backwards to 19.

Answer (score 1):

Yuxiu Li has given the practical answer, here is some background information to it.

The problem is the way division/modulo is defined in C: division rounds towards zero, and modulo is defined by

```
a%b == a - (a/b)*b
```

Since division rounds to zero, `-1/20` is zero. Consequently, `-1%20 == -1 - 0*20` yields `-1`, which is not a valid index into your array.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, leaving off the threading, here is a test program that does what you want.  But you probably want to add something to ensure that you have at least 3 readings (I didn't bother with that).  But the important calculation is taking the current position (bufferPos), and finding the 3 (N) previous values.

Oh, and where I commented lock and unlock, put your thread locking...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BUFSIZE (20)
int bufferPos = 0;
int Databuffer[BUFSIZE] = {0};
int BufferWrite(int x)
{
    //lock
    Databuffer[bufferPos] = x;
    bufferPos = (bufferPos+1)%BUFSIZE;
    printf("write[%d] %d\n", bufferPos, Databuffer[bufferPos]);
    //unlock
}
int BufferRead(int count)
{
    int rdx;
    int position;
    //lock
    for( rdx=0; rdx<count; ++rdx )
    {
        position = ((bufferPos-1)-rdx);
        if( position<0 ) position = position+BUFSIZE;
        printf("read[%d:%d] %d\n", rdx, position, Databuffer[position]);
    }
    //unlock
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int ndx; int val;
    char line[999];
    for( ndx=0; ndx<100; ++ndx )
    {
        fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin);
        BufferWrite(atoi(line));
        if( ndx%7 == 0 )  //read a few, occasionally
        {
            BufferRead(3);
        }
    }
}
```